# What are the benefits of using new over closures

Tags: javascript, closures

I've been programming in JS for over a year now, mainly in angularJS. And I can honestly say I've never made a function use prototypical inheritance. When ever i need a class like object that has private data, I use the factory pattern and closures to create classes. I can honestly say I've never needed to use the this key word.

I'm trying to learn node, and it uses prototypical inheritance pretty heavily so it seems. So there has to be a pretty big benefit of using it over closures.  Can someone explain the main advantages of using prototypes and what not?

Comment: Debugging can be easier since you can see the name of the constructor associated with an object. Code may be easier to follow; data model easier to conceptualize. V8 may also be able to better optimize objects like this (was definitely true in the past, but the optimizer is always always getting tweaked so it fluctuates).

Comment: http://howtonode.org/why-use-closure

Comment: @RobertHarvey that article shows possible benefits of using closures over constructors/prototypes, but doesn't get into possible benefits of constructors/prototypes over closures. This question seems to be about the latter.

Comment: After some research it looks like V8 will not optimize and inline closures. http://wingolog.org/archives/2011/08/02/a-closer-look-at-crankshaft-v8s-optimizing-compiler That might be a little dated. I would love know if this has changed.

Comment: @user133688 [I don't think it has](http://jsperf.com/prototype-vs-closure-constructor). When people talk about avoiding new/constructors, turns out they sometimes mean avoid creating an API where users are forced to use new, but go ahead and use them internally if it makes the code faster / clearer / easier to debug.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from being more familiar to C++/Java programmers, the only advantage I can think of is that prototypes and constructors have arguably better support for traditional OOP-style inheritance.

Imagine you have class A with method foo(), and class B with method bar() that calls foo(). We want class B to be derived from A, so that it can simply call foo() directly and everything works. With constructors and prototypes, this is easy:

```
var A = function() {
    this.x = 42;
};
A.prototype.foo = function() {
    return this.x;
};

var B = function() {
    this.y = 7;
};
B.prototype = new A;
B.prototype.constructor = B;

B.prototype.bar = function() {
    return this.x * this.y;
};

var a = new A;
var b = new B;
console.log(a.foo()); // 42
console.log(b.foo()); // 42
console.log(b.bar()); // 294
```

With closures, you can use the "mixin" approach for public members and methods, but for privates you're basically stuck.

```
var A = function() {
    var x = 42;
    return {
        foo: function() {
            return x;
        }
    };
};

var B = function() {
    var y = 7;
    var obj = {
        bar: function() {
            return x * y;
        }
    };

    // mix in A's public members
    var a = A();
    Object.keys(a).forEach(function(key) {
        obj[key] = a[key];
    });
    return obj;
};

var a = A();
var b = B();
console.log(a.foo()); // 42
console.log(b.foo()); // 42
console.log(b.bar()); // Uncaught ReferenceError: x is not defined
```

As far as I can tell, the only way to make this snippet work is to make x public and use "this.x", at which point it might as well not be using closures anymore. Closures can implement "private" access, but not "protected" access, so if you want to do traditional inheritance you have to leave everything public anyway.

Of course, if you don't do very much inheritance, this is a non-issue. At my job we hardly ever inherit from anything, so we also use closures by default.